# How can I find the "congestion window size" in TCP protocol?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, congestion-control

I know that TCP protocol has a congestion window size to control the network congestion.

However, in the TCP header, I can only find the receive window size, and can't find the [congestion window size](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Transmission_Control_Protocol#/Window_scaling)

Does anyone have ideas about how to find the congestion window size in TCP header? Or if it is doesn't exist in TCP header, where can I find this value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The congestion window size is internal to the TCP implementation. If the particular TCP implementation you are using provides some way to query it, then you can.